# Derivative of a double integral over a variable circular region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, reference-request, leibniz-integral-rule

> Calculate the following derivative
>
> $$\frac{d}{dt}\iint_{D_t}F(x,y,t) \, \mathrm d x \mathrm d y$$
>
> where
>
> $$D_t = \lbrace (x,y) \mid (x-t)^2+(y-t)^2\leq r^2 \rbrace$$

I've read [here$^1$](http://sgpwe.izt.uam.mx/files/users/uami/jdf/proyectos/Derivar_inetegral.pdf) that the answer to the above question is in the form of:
\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}\iint_{D_t}F(x,y,t)dxdy &=\int_{\partial D_t} F(udy-vdx) + \iint_{D_t}\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}dx dy \\
&=\iint_{D_t}\left[\text{div}(F\mathbf{v})+\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}\right]dx dy\end{align}
which is a generalization of Leibniz integral rule.

I don't know how I can calculate $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{n}$ or $u$ and $v$ in my problem. The paper states that $\mathbf{v}$ with components $u$ and $v$ is the velocity and $\mathbf{n}$ is the normal vector.

Also, I would be grateful if someone could introduce some other references on the derivative of such double integrals to me.

$^1$: Harley Flanders,  [**Differentiation under the integral sign**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2319163), Am. Math. Mon. 80, 615-627 (1973). [ZBL0266.26010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0266.26010).

---

The following reference was very handy for me:

J. Haslinger and R. Mäkinen,  [**Introduction to shape optimization: theory, approximation, and computation**](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1.9780898718690.fm), Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics (2003).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your domain $D_t$ is simply the transport of a disk by the vector $\mathbf v = (1,1)$. Because this is a constant vector, its actually easier to just use a simple change of variables:
$$ \frac{d}{d t} \iint_{D_{t}} F(x, y, t) d x d y= \frac{d}{d t}\iint_{D_0} F(x+t,y+t,t)dxdy = \iint_{D_0}  \frac{d}{d t}(F(x+t,y+t,t))dxdy= \iint_{D_0}  (\partial_xF+\partial_yF+\partial_t F)(x+t,y+t,t)dxdy = \iint_{D_t}\partial_xF+\partial_yF+\partial_t Fdxdy. $$

This formula is a special case of the Reynolds Transport Formula.  The great book of Bertozzi and Majda, Vorticity and Incompressible Flow[(Google Books)](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Vorticity_and_Incompressible_Flow.html?id=Lmcz0uwHj_8C&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) on page 5 has the statement and proof. I'll sketch what $\mathbf v$ is, and then sketch the proof from this book, but perhaps the book A First Course in Continuum Mechanics[(Amazon)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521714249) by Gonzales and Stuart will be more gentle (a first hint of this is that I'd suggest you read from page 137, instead of page 5...)

Suppose $F=(\mathbf x,t)$ is a sufficiently smooth function of $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n,t\in\mathbb R$. The velocity acting on particles, $\mathbf v(\mathbf X,t) \in \mathbb R^n$ moves $\mathbf x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$ to the point $\mathbf X=\mathbf X(t,\mathbf x_0) \in \mathbb R^n$ via the particle-trajectory ODE,
$$\begin{cases} \frac{d}{dt}{\mathbf X} = \mathbf v(\mathbf X,t),\\ \mathbf X(0,\mathbf x_0) = \mathbf x_0.\end{cases}$$
Applying this to each point in $D_0$, we have $D_t = \mathbf X(t,D_0) = \{ \mathbf X(t,\mathbf x_0) : \mathbf x_0 \in D_0\}$.

In your case, observe that $D_t $ is is the image under translation of $D_0$ by $t\binom{1}{1}$. Hence, $\mathbf v = \binom{1}{1}$ is actually constant.

To prove the formula in the general case, apply a change of variables to write the integral as an integral over the initial positions of the particles $\mathbf x_0 = \mathbf X(t,\cdot)^{-1}(\mathbf x)$. This gives
$$ \iint_{D_t} F(\mathbf x,t) d\mathbf x = \iint_{D_0} F(\mathbf X(t,\mathbf  x_0),t) J d\mathbf x_0 , $$
where $J=J(t,\mathbf x_0)$ is the Jacobian determinant $J d\mathbf x_0  = d\mathbf x$,
$$ J(t,\mathbf x_0) = \det (\nabla \mathbf  X(t,\mathbf x_0))=\det (\nabla_{\mathbf x_0} \mathbf  X(t,\mathbf x_0)).$$

Taking the gradient in $\mathbf x_0$ of the particle-trajectory ODE gives

$$\begin{cases} \frac{d}{dt}{\nabla \mathbf X} = \nabla \mathbf v(\mathbf X,t)\nabla \mathbf X ,\\ \nabla \mathbf X(0,\mathbf x_0) = I .\end{cases}$$

By Jacobi's formula[(Wikipedia page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula),
$$ \frac{d}{d t} \operatorname{det} A(t)=\operatorname{tr}\left(\operatorname{adj}(A(t)) \frac{d A(t)}{d t}\right),$$
we deduce (using  $\operatorname{tr}(ABC)= \operatorname{tr}(BCA)$ and $(\operatorname{adj} A) A = \det A$ )
$$\frac{dJ}{dt} = \operatorname{tr}(\nabla \mathbf v(\mathbf X,t))J = \nabla\cdot\mathbf v(\mathbf X,t) J. $$
Pushing the derivative into the integral without worry, then applying chain rule and product rule gives the result, since
$$\frac{d}{dt} \Big( F(\mathbf X,t) J \Big) 
= 
\nabla F(\mathbf X,t)\cdot \frac{d}{dt} \mathbf X  J + (\partial_t F)(\mathbf X,t)J  + F(\mathbf X,t) \frac{d}{dt} J = \Big ( \nabla F(\mathbf X,t) \cdot \mathbf v(X,t) +  (\partial_t F)(\mathbf X,t)+ F(\mathbf X,t) \nabla\cdot \mathbf v(\mathbf X,t) \Big) J.  $$

Of course in your case this simplifies greatly to the result I first computed, since your $\mathbf v$ is incompressible with $J\equiv 1$.

(In fact, this formula justifies the name "incompressible": in the special case $F\equiv 1$, it shows that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf v = 0$ iff the volume of $D_t$ is constant in $t$.)

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful idea of change of variables. I didn't think of the problem in this way! I deduce from your answer that $\text{div}(F\mathbf{v})=\partial_xF+\partial_yF$ so $\mathbf{v}=(1,1)$. But I don't understand why this is true.

Comment: @SMA.D actually the change of variables is the first step in the proof of the general case. It's $(1,1)$ because this is the velocity of the set $D_t$. I suggest drawing a few of the sets if this is not clear.

Comment: Intuitively it's correct. But to drive it analytically should I calculate $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ over $(x-t)^2+(y-t)^2=r^2$?

Comment: I couldn't find this generalization of Leibniz integral rule in intermediate calculus books. Do you know any reference book for this generalization?

Comment: @SMA.D I've added a reference and a sketch of the proof in the general case.